# Finding the first matching whole word given a substring in a long text in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a full sentence like the following.

"Stackoverflow is the best and stackoverflow.com rocks !!!"

I need to find the first whole word matching a given sub-string. e.g., if the input is "overflow" the result should be "Stackoverflow" only as it is the first word that contains the given word.

I tried the following snippet but does not work for me.

```
String fullText="Stackoverflow is the best and stackoverflow.com rocks !!!";
String token = "overflow";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(token);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fullText);
while (matcher.find())
{
     System.out.println("Whole word is "+matcher.group());
}
```

I get "overflow" as output. What could be wrong with my code?

Comment: Replace `while` with `if` with `String token = "\\w*overflow\\w*";`.

Comment: `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w*"+Pattern.quote(token)+"\\w*");`

Comment: Use regular expression with global search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What could be wrong with my code?

because your regex is matching only `overflow` not the word that contains it

Use the following regex instead :

```
\\b\\S*overflow\\S*
```

```
String token = "\\b\\S*overflow\\S*";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(token);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fullText);
if (matcher.find())
{
     System.out.println("Whole word is :"+matcher.group());
}
```

explanation:

- `\b` matches word boundary
- `\\S*` matches zero or more none space character
- `overflow`  mataches overflow literally
- `\\S*` matches zero or more non space characters

Alternative two: using split and iterate through each word and break when find the word

```
String fullText="Stackoverflow is the best and stackoverflow.com rocks !!!";
String [] strWords = fullText.split("\\s");
for(String strWord:strWords){
    if(strWord.contains("overflow")){
        System.out.println(strWord);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: [`\\b[^\\s]*overflow[^\\s]*`](https://regex101.com/r/76OaQS/1) might match too much. [My solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52613625/matching-the-first-matching-whole-word-given-a-substring-in-a-long-text-in-java#comment92161709_52613625) is safer.

Comment: No, it is not that great as you see.

Comment: Those are identical. Identically unsafe here.

Comment: Then there is a better solution without a regex here since most probably OP defines a word as a sequence of non-whitespace chars.

Answer (score 1):

Issue in that, what you not use the regular expression in token. You just posting exactly string in Mather, he find exactly that string and that all.

if you want to specify word search conditions, you may use pattern of regular expressions http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Regular_expressions_1__Special_characters.html.

In you case it look like: (I added into text one more word: stackowerflowr)

---

- all words, as start any chars, include 'overflow' and end with space:

  ```
  String fullText="Stackoverflow is the best and stackoverflow.com rocks !!! stackoverflowr";
  String token = "[a-zA-Z]+overflow ";
  ```

  **Whole word is Stackoverflow**

---

- all words, as start and finish any chars (no digits or symbols)

  ```
  String fullText="Stackoverflow is the best and stackoverflow.com rocks !!! stackoverflowr";
  String token = "[a-zA-Z]+overflow[a-zA-Z]+"
  ```

  **Whole word is stackoverflowr**

---

- all words, as start any chars, include 'overflow' + '.' + any chars

  ```
  String fullText="Stackoverflow is the best and stackoverflow.com rocks !!! stackoverflowr";
  String token = "[a-zA-Z]+overflow[.][a-z]+"
  ```

  **Whole word is stackoverflow.com**

> [a-zA-Z] - include any alphabet char
>
> '+' the plus sign is the match-one-or-more quantifier.
>
> . the dot matches any character except the newline symbol.

- also you can to add special symbol '|' (or) for search more variants, but be careful - if the template is suitable for different variants, then only the first one will be determined

  ```
  String fullText="Stackoverflow is the best and stackoverflow.com rocks !!! stackoverflowr";
  String token = "[a-zA-Z]+overflow |[a-zA-Z]+overflow[.][a-z]+";
  ```

  **Whole word is Stackoverflow**

  **Whole word is stackoverflow.com**